# Checking if $B_t^3 $ and $3tB_t$ are martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

$$\mathbb{E}[ B_t^3 - 3tB_t + 3B_t | \mathcal{F}_s]$$

$$\mathbb{E}[B_t^3 | \mathcal{F}_s] - 3\mathbb{E}[t B_t | \mathcal{F}_s\}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[(B_t^3 - B_s^3 + B_s^3) | \mathcal{F}_s] + [ not \space sure \space about \space this ]$$

Using $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ for cube expansions, with $a = B_t - B_s, b = B_s$

... I have tried to simplify this expression, but nothing fruitful yielded.

I got $$ B_t^3 - B_t^2B_s + B_tB_s - 2B_sB_t^2 + 2B_tB_s^3 - 2B_s^3$$

Which must be a mistake... but is there perhaps a better method to approach this?

Also, for the $$-3 \mathbb{E}[t B_t | \mathcal{F}_s] $$ where can I proceed from here? My instinct tells me $t$ is $\mathcal{F}$ - measurable, although I am not 100% confident.

Comment: Hint: Start with $E[(B_t-B_s)^3\mid \mathcal{F}_s] = 0$ and expand the expression inside the expectation. As for $3tB_t$ it is clearly not a martingale.  $E[3tB_t\mid\mathcal{F}_s] = 3tB_s \neq 3sB_s$

Comment: Is this not a different expression entirely? 

also since $\mathcal{F}_s$ is history of $s \leq t$, doesn't that also give the value $t = s$ ?

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}[(B_t - B_s)^3]$$

Comment: If you expand it you will get $B_t^3$ and other terms, which you have to take care of. But you should be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[B_t^3|\mathcal{F}_s]&=E[(B_t-B_s+B_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&=E[(B_t-B_s)^3+3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s+3(B_t-B_s)B_s^2+B_s^3|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&=E[3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s|\mathcal{F}_s]+B_s^3\neq B_s^3\\ 
E[3tB_t|\mathcal{F}_s]&=E[3t(B_t-B_s+B_s)|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&=E[3t(B_t-B_s)|\mathcal{F}_s]+E[3tB_s|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
&=3tB_s \neq 3sB_s
\end{align}

---

EDIT:
\begin{align}
E[3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s|\mathcal{F}_s]&=3B_sE[(B_t-B_s)^2|\mathcal{F}_s]\\
=3B_s(t-s)
\end{align}

Comment: If I could investigate the first case further, after expanding all the brackets, do they cancel out leaving only $B_t^3$ ? Is it purely algebra, or were there intermediate actions taken

Comment: hm, I am not sure if I get your point. But you mean to expand $(B_t-B_s)^3$?

Comment: oh, sorry. I swore I saw you stating the first case was a martingale. 

Is there a way to simplify the $$E[3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s|\mathcal{F}_s]$$ term further?

Comment: You are right about the answer, I made an edit a bit later. About simplification: sure, see the edit.

Comment: Ahh, right. Awesome thanks for that!

Comment: you are most welcome!

Comment: How come when I try to expand the expression
$(B_t-B_s)^3 + 3(B_t-B_s)B_s^2$ it doesn't cancel out to leave only the $3(B_t-B_s)^2B_s$ like you have though? 

Did those terms cancel out purely from their expansion, or was another trick involved

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your question is why $E(B_t-B_s)^3|\mathcal{F}_s=0$: this is bc of symmetry and normality.

Comment: Yep, got it. is it a similar instance for $E(3(B_t-B_s)B_s^2|\mathcal{F}_s)$ ?

Comment: In this case we have $E3(B_t-B_s)B_s^2|\mathcal{F}_s=3B_s^2E(B_t-B_s)|\mathcal{F}_s$ bc of conditioning. and we know that the expectation here is zero.